# How do I move the Main Camera in Unity when I click on a sprite?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a simple VR Tour in Unity, and I want to move the camera to the next sphere (or at all at this point) when I click on a sprite that is hovering in the air. Right now, when I run this code, I get the "Sprite Clicked" message in the console, but the camera doesn't move at all. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DebugOnClick : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    void OnMouseDown () {
    Debug.Log("Sprite Clicked");
    Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(5.0f, 5.0f, 5.0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question: Is `Camera.main` a VR thing?

Comment: @Savaria `Camera.main` refers to the camera in the scene with the `MainCamera` tag. It is not exclusive to VR. If there is no camera in the scene with the `MainCamera` tag then that line of code will [result in a `NullReferenceException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52242733/10209883).

Comment: Do you have your main camera as a child of another object that is also moving?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't let me comment (not enough rep) so I must pop this in as an answer.

If you're using some given VR scripts already, it could be possible that they're syncing the camera position constantly to where they should be relative to the player's headset position.

Meaning that after this move via script, the camera will be moved back instantly.

If that is the case, you need to move the player avatar themselves to the correct position rather than the camera.