# Error In my code (NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object ) how to fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Having this error

I have tried many options to pass the reference to null such as:

But it didn't work. I know it's a simple error, but I'm new in coding. A little help will be appreciated a lot.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class Paintable : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Brush;
    public float BrushSize = 0.1f;
    public RenderTexture RTexture;

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            // error is in this line 
            var Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if(Physics.Raycast(Ray, out hit))
            {
                var go = Instantiate(Brush, hit.point + Vector3.up * 0.1f, Quaternion.identity, transform);
                go.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * BrushSize;
            }
        }
    }
```

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object Paintable.Update () (at
>   Assets/Datafiles/Scripts/Paintable.cs:23)

It is giving me error when I start a play mode in unity to draw on a plane with a brush.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Camera.main null reference exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52242441/camera-main-null-reference-exception)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that there is no camera with the tag of `MainCamera`. You'll just have to check your `Camera` object(s) in the editor and change their tag to `MainCamera` using the dropdown.

Source: https://answers.unity.com/questions/462964/nullreferenceexception-in-cameramainscreenpointtor.html